# PyBrain Reinforcement Learning - Maze and Graph

Tags: python-2.7, reinforcement-learning, pybrain

I was trying to implement in PyBrain something similar to a Maze problem. However, it's more similar to a room with an emergency exit, where you leave an agent in one of the rooms to find the exit.
To convert this to a computer method a bi-directional graph could be used with the weights showing the path between the rooms.

I tried to implement a new environment, but I'm kind of lost on what should be what.
For example, based on the abstract environment class I have thought about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

class RoomEnv(Environment):
    # number of action values acceptable by the environment
    # Two events: go forward and go back through the door (but, how we know what room is connect to another?)
    indim = 2
    # Maybe a matrix where 0 is no connection and 1 is a connection(?)
    #            A,B,C,D,E,F
    #indim = array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],  # A
                    [0,0,0,0,0,1],  # B
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # C
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # D
                    [0,0,0,0,0,1],  # E
                    [0,0,0,0,0,1],  # F
                  ])

    # the number of sensors is the number of the rooms
    outdim = 6

    def getSensors(self):
        # Initial state:
        # Could be any room, maybe something random(?)

    def performAction(self, action):
        # We should look at all the states possible to learn what are the best option to go to the outside state.
        # Maybe a for loop that goes through all the paths and use some weight to know where is the best option?

        print "Action performed: ", action

    def reset(self):
        #Most environments will implement this optional method that allows for reinitialization.
```

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **pybrain**, you can define the room as an array and then pass the structure to the Maze to make a new environment. for example:

```
structure = array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

# defining the environment
environment = Maze(structure, (7, 7))
```

in the above example, the 1s show the walls and the 0s show the grids that the agent can walk on. So you can modify the structure to make your own.